# How to get value from email content in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, web-api-testing

I am using IMAP to read the email content using BeanShell sampler. I am able to read the email content and able to store in a variable.

Now I am looking for a solution to read the particular value from the email content and store in another variable. Please provide me the best way to handle this situation.

In the following response, I want to store the randomly generated id which is in the URL: https://abc.abc.in/abc/verification.html?5f3a59b8-f1af-4951-8ca4-2836c4307838

i.e : 5f3a59b8-f1af-4951-8ca4-2836c4307838

**Sample response email Content:**

Sehr geehrte/r Daitha1 Shankar11354262,



                Willkommen bei XXXXXXXXXXX

Es wurde ein neuer ON!Track Benutzerzugang für Sie erstellt. Um den Zugang zu aktivieren, bestätigen Sie bitte Ihre E-Mail Adresse, indem Sie auf folgenden Link klicken:


https://abc.abc.in/abc/verification.html?5f3a59b8-f1af-4951-8ca4-2836c4307838
 

Aus Sicherheitsgründen ist dieser Link nur 24 Stunden gültig. Falls Sie Ihre E-Mail Adresse innerhalb von 24 Stunden nicht bestätigen konnten, gehen Sie bitte auf die ?Passwort vergessen??- Seite um eine neue Bestätigungs E-Mail zu erhalten.

Ihr Benutzername lautet shankar@api.com


Gehen Sie zur Seite ?Passwort vergessen?


**Mit besten Grüßen,


Ihr QA Team**

[image]

[image: Email Content]

Answer (score 2):

If you are saving the email content into a JMeter variable in Beanshell Sampler say "myEmailContent".Try to follow below step to extract id.

1) Add regular Expression extractor to your Bean shell sampler.And check JMeter variable in Appy to section and provide your JMeter varible name.

2) Add "**verification.html\?(.*)<**" in regular expression and provide a reference variable say "ID".

3)Use vars.get("ID") to retrieve value in beanshell sampler or ${ID} as per your sampler.

[image]

**note**:I have given regular expression as per your screenshot.Remove "<" if it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to your question itself,

1. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of the Beanshell Sampler
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Apply to -> JMeter Variable -> email content variable reference name
   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `id`
   - Regular Expression: `https://abc.abc.in/abc/verification.html\?([a-f\d]{8}-[a-f\d]{4}-[a-f\d]{4}-[a-f\d]{4}-([a-f\d]){12})`
   - Template: `$1$`

In general:

1. JMeter comes with [Mail Reader Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Mail_Reader_Sampler) so you don't need to go for scripting in order to read messages via IMAP protocol, see [How to Create a JMeter Script to Check Email During Registration AND Grab the Confirmation URL](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-create-jmeter-script-check-email-during-registration-and-grab-confirmation-url) for example use case.
2. If you "have to" use scripting to overcome a JMeter limitation consider using [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) as Beanshell performance is not that good and it may become the bottleneck in your test.